# PMT in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

I am trying to code the equivalent to the EXCEL PMT function.

in JavaScript, the formula looks like this:

```
function PMT (ir, np, pv, fv ) {
 /*
 ir - interest rate per month
 np - number of periods (months)
 pv - present value
 fv - future value (residual value)
 */
 pmt = ( ir * ( pv * Math.pow ( (ir+1), np ) + fv ) ) / ( ( ir + 1 ) * ( Math.pow ( (ir+1), np) -1 ) );
 return pmt;
}
```

This is great for PMT calcs where Type =1 (i.e. payments occur at the start of the period)

However, I'm trying to code for a Type 0 scenario (i.e. payments occur at the end of the period)).

Any math wizards out there who can tell me how to modify my formula?

Comment: Before you write your formulas, can you actually describe how they work? If you can't, better get over to Wikipedia and start reading ;)

Answer (score 4):

@dps123: When I recently had to work with some financial equations to convert functions from an Excel workbook, I came across the [EGM Mathematical Finance class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/3028.html), which tries to mimic Excel functions. It might be worth having a look at, if only to see how the functions look/were made to work like Excel's.

**Example usage:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Case use of financial class.
 * 
 * @version   $Id: financial_example.php,v 1.0.5 2004-06-23 09:03:56-05 egarcia Exp $
 * @author    Enrique Garcia M. <egarcia@egm.as>
 * @copyright (c) 2002-2004 EGM :: Ingenieria sin fronteras
 * @since     Saturday, November 30, 2002
 **/

/***************************************************************************
 *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *   (at your option) any later version.
 *
 ***************************************************************************/

include('financial_class.php');

echo '<pre>';
echo 'FV: ' . $f->FV(1.1, 1/360, 0, -100) . "\n";
echo 'PV: ' . $f->PV(1.1, 1/360, 0, -100.206306226) . "\n";
echo 'PMT: ' . $f->PMT(1.1, 1/360, -100) . "\n";
echo 'PMT: ' . $f->PMT(1.1, 1/360, 0, -100.206306226) . "\n";
echo 'NPER: ' . $f->NPER(1.1, 53428.7980679, -100) . "\n";
echo 'NPER: ' . $f->NPER(1.1, 0, -100, -100.206306226) . "\n";
echo 'FV: ' . $f->FV(0.1, 1/360, 0, -100) . "\n";
echo 'PV: ' . $f->PV(0.1, 1/360, 0, -100.026478555) . "\n";
echo 'PMT: ' . $f->PMT(0.1, 1/360, -100) . "\n";
echo 'PMT: ' . $f->PMT(0.1, 1/360, 0, -100.026478555) . "\n";
echo 'NPER: ' . $f->NPER(1.1, 37776.4114948, -100) . "\n";
echo 'NPER: ' . $f->NPER(1.1, 0, -100, -100.026478555) . "\n";
echo 'EFFECT: ' . $f->EFFECT(0.0525, 4) . "\n";
echo 'NOMINAL: ' . $f->NOMINAL(0.053543, 4) . "\n";
echo 'NPV: ' . $f->NPV(0.1, array(-10000,3000,4200,6800)) . "\n";
echo 'XNPV: ' . $f->XNPV(0.09, array(-10000,2750,4250,3250,2750), array(
    mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2008),
    mktime(0,0,0,3,1,2008),
    mktime(0,0,0,10,30,2008),
    mktime(0,0,0,2,15,2009),
    mktime(0,0,0,4,1,2009),
    )) . "\n";
echo 'XIRR: ' . $f->XIRR(array(-10000,2750,4250,3250,2750), array(
    mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2008),
    mktime(0,0,0,3,1,2008),
    mktime(0,0,0,10,30,2008),
    mktime(0,0,0,2,15,2009),
    mktime(0,0,0,4,1,2009),
    ), 0.1) . "\n";
echo 'IRR: ' . $f->IRR(array(-70000,12000,15000,18000,21000)) . "\n";
echo 'DISC: ' . $f->DISC(
    mktime(0,0,0,1,25,2007),
    mktime(0,0,0,6,15,2007),
    97.975,
    100,
    0) . "\n";
echo 'DISC: ' . $f->DISC(
    mktime(0,0,0,1,25,2007),
    mktime(0,0,0,6,15,2009),
    97.975,
    100,
    1) . "\n";
echo 'DISC: ' . $f->DISC(
    mktime(0,0,0,1,25,2007),
    mktime(0,0,0,6,15,2007),
    97.975,
    100,
    2) . "\n";
echo 'DISC: ' . $f->DISC(
    mktime(0,0,0,1,25,2007),
    mktime(0,0,0,6,15,2007),
    97.975,
    100,
    3) . "\n";
echo 'DISC: ' . $f->DISC(
    mktime(0,0,0,1,25,2007),
    mktime(0,0,0,6,15,2007),
    97.975,
    100,
    4) . "\n";
echo 'INTRATE: ' . $f->INTRATE(
    mktime(0,0,0,2,15,2008),
    mktime(0,0,0,5,15,2008),
    1000000,
    1014420,
    2) . "\n";
echo 'IPMT: ' . $f->IPMT(0.1/12, 3, 3, 8000) . "\n";
echo 'IPMT: ' . $f->IPMT(0.1, 3, 3, 8000) . "\n";
echo 'RECEIVED: ' . $f->RECEIVED(
    mktime(0,0,0,2,15,2008),
    mktime(0,0,0,5,15,2008),
    1000000,
    0.0575,
    2) . "\n";
echo 'DOLLARDE: ' . $f->DOLLARDE(1.02, 16) . "\n";
echo 'DOLLARDE: ' . $f->DOLLARDE(1.1, 32) . "\n";
echo 'DOLLARFR: ' . $f->DOLLARFR(1.125, 16) . "\n";
echo 'DOLLARFR: ' . $f->DOLLARFR(1.125, 32) . "\n";
echo 'FVSCHEDULE: ' . $f->FVSCHEDULE(1, array(0.09,0.11,0.1)) . "\n";
echo 'PPMT: ' . $f->PPMT(0.1/12, 1, 2*12, 2000) . "\n";
echo 'PPMT: ' . $f->PPMT(0.08, 10, 10, 200000) . "\n";
echo 'RATE: ' . $f->RATE(4*12,-200, 8000) . "\n";
echo 'RATE: ' . $f->RATE(4*12,-200, 8000)*12 . "\n";
echo 'SYD: ' . $f->SYD(30000, 7500, 10, 10) . "\n";
echo 'SLN: ' . $f->SLN(30000, 7500, 10) . "\n";
echo 'DDB: ' . $f->DDB(1000000, 100000, 10, 4) . "\n";
echo 'DELTA: ' . $f->DELTA(5, 4) . "\n";
echo 'DELTA: ' . $f->DELTA(5, 5) . "\n";
echo 'PRICEDISC: ' . $f->PRICEDISC(mktime(0,0,0,2,16,2008), mktime(0,0,0,3,1,2008), 0.0525, 100, 2) . "\n";
echo 'YIELDDISC: ' . $f->YIELDDISC(mktime(0,0,0,2,16,2008), mktime(0,0,0,3,1,2008), 99.795, 100, 2) . "\n";
echo 'COUPNUM: ' . $f->COUPNUM(mktime(0,0,0,1,25,2007), mktime(0,0,0,11,15,2008), 2, 1) . "\n";
echo 'COUPDAYBS: ' . $f->COUPDAYBS(mktime(0,0,0,1,25,2007), mktime(0,0,0,11,17,2008), 1, 1) . "\n";
echo 'VDB: ' . $f->VDB(2400,300,10*365,0,1) . "\n";
echo 'VDB: ' . $f->VDB(2400,300,10*12,0,1) . "\n";
echo 'VDB: ' . $f->VDB(2400,300,10,0,1) . "\n";
echo 'VDB: ' . $f->VDB(2400,300,10*12,6,18) . "\n";
echo 'VDB: ' . $f->VDB(2400,300,10*12,6,18,1.5) . "\n";
echo 'VDB: ' . $f->VDB(2400,300,10,0,0.875,1.5) . "\n";
echo 'MIRR: ' . $f->MIRR(array(-120000,39000,30000,21000,37000,46000), 0.1, 0.12) . "\n";
echo 'MIRR: ' . $f->MIRR(array(-120000,39000,30000,21000), 0.1, 0.12) . "\n";
echo 'MIRR: ' . $f->MIRR(array(-120000,39000,30000,21000,37000,46000), 0.1, 0.14) . "\n";
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

@dps

You would need to amend the denominator where the interest factor is changed to `(ir * type + 1)`

When it is an annuity due meaning start of period payments the value of `1` for `Type` will insure the interest factor `(ir + 1)` and when it is an ordinary annuity meaning end of period payments the value of `0` for `Type` will reduce the factor to `1`.

```
pmt = ( ir * ( pv * Math.pow ( (ir+1), np ) + fv ) ) / ( ( ir * type + 1 ) * ( Math.pow ( (ir+1), np) -1 ) );
```

The equation you presented is actually how MS Excel computes 5 Time Value of Money functions namely `FV`, `PV`, `PMT`, `NPER` and `RATE`. The first three are easily calculated by rearranging the equation and solve for `FV`, `PV` or `PMT`. For `NPER` and `RATE` other methods are needed, some use a binary search algorithm to find `RATE` yet a better and elegant solution to find `RATE` is to be had with Newton Raphson method.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code in java:

```
double pmt = ((pv - fv) * ir / (1 - Math.pow((1 + ir), -np)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a math wiz, but a simple google search turned this thread up:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/370948-pmt-function-does-anyone-know-the-formula.html

Here he has the following formula for type=0:

```
pmt = ((pv - fv) * ir / (1 - (1 + ir) ^ -(np)));
```

Maybe this will work for you :)

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried that formula in JS but it does not give the same ouput as my formula. var pmt = ((100000 - 0) * (7.5/12) / (1 - (1 + (7.5/12)) ^ -(48)));
    var pmv = PMT2((7.5/1200),48,100000,0);

Comment: @dps123: well in one you use ir = 7.5/12 and in the other you use 7.5/1200 so of course they will give different results.

Comment: yes. My formula expects the rate should be divided by 12 and results the correct value. Also i changed to divide only by 12 and still the results are different.