# vb script to javascript

Tags: vba, vbscript, javascript

Can anyone help me to convert this VB script to equivalent Javascript please.

```
PMT = ((PV - FV) * rate/ (1 - (1 + rate) ^ -(nper)))
```

Comment: This is already valid javascript, you should keep this in the existing thread

Comment: @Martin Jespersen JavaScript doesn't have an exponentiation operator ...

Comment: Sorry Martin, ^ is not a power function in JavaScript.

Comment: @Everyone: sorry, my bad *shakes his tired friday head*

Comment: @Pointy @Diodeus maybe he wanted a bitwise XOR !

Answer (score 6):

Probably

```
var PMT = ((PV - FV) * rate / (1 - Math.pow(1 + rate, -nper)));
```

JavaScript numbers are always (at heart) floating-point values, so when you're dealing with money things can get somewhat weird.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, I added this values : var pmt = ((100000 - 0) * (7.5/12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (7.5/12), -48))); both result does not match.. any ideas please..

Comment: My objective is to do the following math : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353511/pmt-in-javascript

Comment: The result doesn't match **what**??  Also, if the interest rate is 7.5%, you probably should be using 0.075 and not 7.5.